# Excluding on JQuery selector correct in console, code still runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-selectors, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working on the print styling for forms in a web app which uses Kendo. In short: before printing, I append `<div>` tags containing each `input`'s value, and hide the `input` tags. The exception is the Kendo MaskedTextBox, as the mask displays the data as intended, and its raw value does not contain the mask.

It's working as intended for everything else - the `input`s are hidden, and only the appended `div`s are shown.
For the masked textbox, however, the `input` is shown (correct), but the `div` is still being appended (incorrect).

**HTML structure** (copied from Edge Dev Tools *(F12)*):

```html
<div class="mws-form-col-2-8">
    <label>Masked TextBox</label>
    <span class="k-widget k-maskedtextbox" style="width: 100%;">
        <input class="k-textbox" id="maskTest" name="maskTest"
               value="1234567890" data-role="maskedtextbox"
               style="width:100%" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"></span>
    </span>
    <script>kendo.syncReady(...)</script>
    <!-- Appended div here: <div class="inputPrint">1234567890</div> -->
</div>
```

**Print css**:

```css
input:not(.k-textbox),
span.k-widget:not(.k-maskedtextbox) {
    display: none!important;
}
```

**Javascript**:

This function is bound to the `window.onbeforeprint` event and is called from `$(document).ready()` when the media type is "print" (Edge/Chrome can emulate css media type, which I'm using to debug this).

```js
function beforePrint() {
    // exclude input.k-textbox
    $("input:not(.k-textbox)").each(function () {
        // exclude input with .k-maskedtextbox parent
        //if (! $(this).parents(".k-maskedtextbox").length) {
        if ($(this).parents(".k-maskedtextbox").length <= 0) {
            // check if the .inputPrint div already exists
            if ($(this).siblings(".inputPrint").length) {
                // set text of existing
                $(this).siblings(".inputPrint").text($(this).val());
            }
            else {
                // append a div displaying its value to its parent
                $(this).parent().append("<div class='inputPrint'>" + $(this).val() + "</div>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the selector on the first line of the function (`input:not(.k-textbox)`) is the same as in the css.

**Display**:

```
Masked TextBox          ←- Label
╭────────────────╮
| (123) 456-7890 |      ←- input
╰────────────────╯
╭────────────────╮
| 1234567890     |      ←- appended div
╰────────────────╯
```

When I try to figure out how this could have happened by checking some things in the console, this is what I get:

```
$("#maskTest").is("input:not(.k-textbox)")
false

$("#maskTest").is(".k-textbox")
true
```

This input should not have even been included in the `.each`.

```
$("#maskTest").parents(".k-maskedtextbox").length
1

$("#maskTest").parents(".k-maskedtextbox").length <= 0
false
```

If it *was* included, it should not have entered the first `if` statement.

How is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the Kendo MVC wrappers expand the inputs into kendo controls in the `kendo.syncReady` event, which runs *after* `$(document).ready` is complete.

So on my initial page load, the input I was checking only looked like this:

```
<input id="maskTest" name="maskTest" style="width:100%" value="1234567890" />
```